# Row is inserted/appears unexpectedly on SELECT with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working with a database created by a colleague who left the company and noticed some behaviours that I cannot explain.

There is a table with 20 entrys like this:

```
  id  |  value  |  timestamp
==============================
  12  |  asdf   |  01.01.2020
  566 |  qwer   |  22.02.2020
  23  |  yxcv   |  03.12.2019
```

Now I was looking for an entry with the id 55. Selecting all entrys without a where clause didn't bring up a row with id 55 but as soon as I added `WHERE id = 55` to my query an entry showed up.

There are no triggers defined for that table. The **SQL Server Profiler** didn't help me either as there was just one entry for my query - nothing else.

How is this possible?
I'm also glad for any hints to track down the source of this behaviour.

**EDIT:**

The query as it was asked for in the comments:

```
SELECT * FROM map_active WHERE id = 55
```

Comment: Please include the SQL query that is giving error.

Comment: Top two things that can cause this: 1) it's actually a view and the results are non-deterministic; 2) index corruption.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is a table. Is there a way to fix a possible index corruption?

Comment: @ErikT., execute [`DBCC CHECKTABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checktable-transact-sql): `DBCC CHECKTABLE(N'dbo.map_active');`